# Summarize all cells until a new entry appears

Tags: google-sheets

For my personal budget calculations i have a long google spreadsheet which basically sums up monthly costs, etc.

Obviously the amount of entries per month varies, so i want/need a formula which determines how long the list for the current month is, based on a label in an otherwise empty column on the side.

Best explained with this example:

```
Jan 2017 | Testytestname | Sum
         | 200           | Calc_Sum_Formula_here -> 500
         | 300           |
         |               |
Feb 2017 | Testytestname | Sum
         | 350           | Calc_Sum_Formula_pasted_again -> 450
         | 100           |
```

I tried to find fitting examples on the internet and here, but none were able to do this without messing up the layout severely (which i'd rather not do).

Thanks for answers in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how much you are willing to change, but if you will extend the month year to the rows with numbers this will work. I have also shared my test spreadsheet. Put this in C1:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF((A1:A<>A2:A)*(A1:A<>""),SUMIF($A$2:$A,A1:A,$B$2:$B),""))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gdPiDRm1cVJGgC01VavWOCuv-cwaBA6fLTUdvTuIDYU/edit?usp=sharing

Good news and bad news. The below formula works with no changes to your data. The bad news is that index/match does not work with arrayformula so you have to put this in C1 and copy it down.

```
=if(istext(B1),SUM(B1:INDEX(B1:B,MATCH(TRUE,(B1:B=""),0))),"")
```

I hope this solves your problem. I am adding it to Sheet2 of the shared spreadsheet.

Comment: First of all: Thanks! Really no way to avoid replicating the month there?^^

Comment: Not that I have found, but I'm still trying.

Comment: Sorry, did now (seems SO doesn't send emails for edits). Works flawlessly, thank you very much!